# When I automatically update a HighCharts chart every minute, the CPU gradually overloads, and the browser locks up

Tags: highcharts

I have a HighCharts chart that we program to automatically update with our latest data every minute. Initially the CPU runs low, about 1-3 % usage, with occasional brief spikes of course. There are 8 series in the chart, and 240 points on each series. All's well for several hours.

Gradually, over a few hours, I see the Chrome process doing the chart taking more and more %, until finally it is locked at 25% or more, and does not drop. At this point the fan on the PC is running non stop so I can hear it happen even if I am not staring at the screen. Eventually, the chart no longer updates automatically, and the Chrome browser becomes unresponsive, and I cannot refresh the page or anything, and have to shut the page down completely and restart the process. Then the CPU % goes back down, and the cycle repeats.

At first we assumed it was our API grabbing and returnning data that was the bottle neck. However, that's not the case because we disabled the line where we actually update the chart, and left all else as before, and the issue went away. No CPU overload, no locked browser page.

Here is the java script setting up the chart:

//By the way, I am using highcharts-ng ( https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)

```
chartConfig[deviceId] = {
chart: {
    type: lineType,  // some chart type, usually be 'area'
    height: 300,
    style: {
        fontSize: '14px'
    }
},
tooltip: {
    style: {
        padding: 10,
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
},
legend: {
    enabled: true,
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    layout: 'horizontal'
},
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function () {
                // var deviceId = this.userOptions.deviceId;
                let index = this.yAxis.userOptions.index;
                showYAxis(deviceId, index);
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
    area: {
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function () {
                // var deviceId = this.userOptions.deviceId;
                let index = this.yAxis.userOptions.index;
                showYAxis(deviceId, index);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
},
rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false
},
scrollbar: {
    enabled: false
},
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        hourButton: {
            text: '1h',
            _titleKey: "myButtonTitle",
            align: 'left',
            x: 10,
            onclick: function () {
                startDate[deviceId] = moment().subtract(1, 'hours').toDate();
                endDate[deviceId] = moment().toDate();
                doQuery(deviceId);    // do some query by API invoke
            }
        },
        dayButton: {
            text: '1d',
            _titleKey: "myButtonTitle",
            align: 'left',
            x: 45,
            onclick: function () {
                startDate[deviceId] = moment().subtract(1, 'days').toDate();
                endDate[deviceId] = moment().toDate();
                doQuery(deviceId); 
            }
        },
        weekButton: {
            text: '1w',
            _titleKey: "myButtonTitle",
            align: 'left',
            x: 80,
            onclick: function () {
                startDate[deviceId] = moment().subtract(1, 'weeks').toDate();
                endDate[deviceId] = moment().toDate();
                doQuery(deviceId);
            }
        },
        oneMonthButton: {
            text: '1mo',
            _titleKey: "myButtonTitle",
            align: 'left',
            x: 115,
            onclick: function () {
                startDate[deviceId] = moment().subtract(1, 'months').toDate();
                endDate[deviceId] = moment().toDate();
                doQuery(deviceId);
            }
        },
        threeMonthButton: {
            text: '3mo',
            _titleKey: "myButtonTitle",
            align: 'left',
            x: 160,
            onclick: function () {
                startDate[deviceId] = moment().subtract(3, 'months').toDate();
                endDate[deviceId] = moment().toDate();
                doQuery(deviceId);
            }
        },
        AllButton: {
            text: 'All',
            _titleKey: "myButtonTitle",
            align: 'left',
            x: 205,
            onclick: function () {
                startDate[deviceId] = moment().subtract(3, 'years').toDate();
                endDate[deviceId] = moment().toDate();
                doQuery(deviceId);
            }
        }
    }
},

xAxis: {
    id: 'x-axis',
    type: 'datetime',
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
        millisecond: '%M:%S',
        second: '%M:%S',
        minute: '%H:%M',
        hour: '%H:%M',
        day: '%e. %b',
        week: '%e. %b',
        month: '%b \'%y',
        year: '%Y'
    },
    labels: {
        style: {
            fontSize: '16px'
        }
    },
    ordinal: false
},
yAxis: [],
series: [],
title: {
    text: deviceNameByMedia
},
boost: {
    useGPUTranslations: true
},
useHighStocks: true,
chartType: 'stock'
```

};

And the HTML line that we comment out to get the problem to disappear is:

```
<highchart layout="row" config="ChartService.getChartConfig()"></highchart>
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: highcharts-ng is an unofficial wrapper. You can try using the official version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular Maybe this issue won't occur then.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your update code!

Could be a problem with boost. Check if the error occurs, when you disable GPUTranslation or when you disable boost completely.
If you reload the complete series try to unload the old series first.

Comment: We tried disabling boost, which did not fix it. I'll try unloading the old series first...

Comment: @Chris were you able to solve this issue? Please post the answer.